# Dataframe groupby - return delta time for log entries

Tags: python, pandas

I've got some log data that I'd like to first group by user_id, then, pick out the, say, 2nd entry. That's done below. The missing step is **the age of each entry relative to the first**, after grouping.

```
dd = pd.DataFrame({'item_id': {0: 0, 1: 4, 2: 6, 3: 8, 4: 9, 5: 1}, 'date': {0: '2013-12-29T17:56:01Z', 1: '2013-12-29T19:44:09Z', 2: '2013-12-29T19:58:05Z', 3: '2013-12-29T20:00:09Z', 4: '2013-12-29T20:13:35Z', 5: '2013-12-29T20:19:56Z'}, 'user_id': {0: 6, 1: 8, 2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 6, 5: 6}})
print "Step 1: Original DataFrame, sorted by date:\n",  dd

g = dd.groupby(by='user_id', sort=False)
print "\nStep 2: Grouped by User ID:\n", g.head()

# Print the 2nd entey (if it exists)
print "\nStep 3: The 2nd user for each entry:\n", g.nth(1).dropna(how='all')

# age?
```

returns:

```
Step 1: Original DataFrame, sorted by date:
                   date  item_id  user_id
0  2013-12-29T17:56:01Z        0        6
1  2013-12-29T19:44:09Z        4        8
2  2013-12-29T19:58:05Z        6        3
3  2013-12-29T20:00:09Z        8        3
4  2013-12-29T20:13:35Z        9        6
5  2013-12-29T20:19:56Z        1        6

Step 2: Grouped by User ID:
                           date  item_id  user_id
user_id                                          
6       0  2013-12-29T17:56:01Z        0        6
        4  2013-12-29T20:13:35Z        9        6
        5  2013-12-29T20:19:56Z        1        6
8       1  2013-12-29T19:44:09Z        4        8
3       2  2013-12-29T19:58:05Z        6        3
        3  2013-12-29T20:00:09Z        8        3

Step 3: The 2nd user for each entry:
                         date  item_id
user_id                               
6        2013-12-29T20:13:35Z        9
3        2013-12-29T20:00:09Z        8
```

But I'd like to print the age (in, say, decimal days) at step 2, relative to the first item_id consumed by that user, so I can judge the age of the log entries in step 3. Is there a pythonic way to do this without iteration?

The desired output is:

```
   user_id                 date  item_id      age
0        3  2013-12-29 20:00:09        8  0:02:04
1        6  2013-12-29 20:13:35        9  2:17:34
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First convert the date from a string column to datetime64[ns] dtype

```
In [21]: dd['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dd['date'])

In [22]: dd
Out[22]: 
                 date  item_id  user_id
0 2013-12-29 17:56:01        0        6
1 2013-12-29 19:44:09        4        8
2 2013-12-29 19:58:05        6        3
3 2013-12-29 20:00:09        8        3
4 2013-12-29 20:13:35        9        6
5 2013-12-29 20:19:56        1        6

[6 rows x 3 columns]
```

sort by the date

```
In [23]: dd.sort_index(by='date')
Out[23]: 
                 date  item_id  user_id
0 2013-12-29 17:56:01        0        6
1 2013-12-29 19:44:09        4        8
2 2013-12-29 19:58:05        6        3
3 2013-12-29 20:00:09        8        3
4 2013-12-29 20:13:35        9        6
5 2013-12-29 20:19:56        1        6

[6 rows x 3 columns]
```

define a function to diff on that column (and just return the rest of the group)

```
In [4]: def f(x):
   ...:     x['diff'] = x['date']-x['date'].iloc[0]
   ...:     return x
   ...: 

In [5]: dd.sort_index(by='date').groupby('user_id').apply(f)
Out[5]: 
                 date  item_id  user_id     diff
0 2013-12-29 17:56:01        0        6 00:00:00
1 2013-12-29 19:44:09        4        8 00:00:00
2 2013-12-29 19:58:05        6        3 00:00:00
3 2013-12-29 20:00:09        8        3 00:02:04
4 2013-12-29 20:13:35        9        6 02:17:34
5 2013-12-29 20:19:56        1        6 02:23:55

[6 rows x 4 columns]
```

the diff is now a timedelta64[ns], see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#time-deltas-conversions) for how to convert/round to a specific frequency (e.g. days).

This is with pandas 0.13 (releasing in next day or 2). Most of this will work in 0.12 as well.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff. The problem is, after the `apply(f)`, I cannot do something like `nth(1)` to return the 2nd value of each group. Any ideas? In other words, the following fails: `dd.groupby('user_id').apply(f).nth(1).dropna(how='all')`

Comment: in ``f`` you could do ``x.head(2).tail(1)`` to do that (you could also do ``x.iloc[1]``, but if you have a groupsize < 2 that will fail. alternatively, you can do a second group/apply (``nth`` is a groupby operation), e.g. ``dd.gropuby('user_id').apply(f).gropuby('user_id').nth(1)``

Comment: also, the function you suggest computes the diff between each subsequent time. I need the diff computed from the **first** action to each subsequent action, so that the first time a user_id appears, that is time zero and each new action has its age computed relative to that first action.

Comment: easy, just do ``x['diff'] = x['date']-x['date'].iloc[0]``

Comment: that worked for me. Please put the second groupby (there's a small typo in the spelling) into the answer so it answers the q'n completely and I'll accept it.

Comment: updated...note that a group with only 1 element will return 0 timedelta (which is what I think you want).