# Iterating within groups in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem that I think involves iterating over individual rows in groups in pandas. If anyone has a vectorized solution though, it would be great. Basically I'm trying to calculate the amount of days a group is in a particular stage:

```
Group    stage    time
  A        1      2000-01-01
  A        1      2000-01-10
  A        2      2000-01-25
  A        2      2000-02-04
  A        2      2000-02-20
  B        1      2000-01-05
  B        1      2000-02-13
  C        3      2000-04-01
```

Would become:

```
Group    stage    time           stage duration
  A        1      2000-01-01           0
  A        1      2000-01-10           9
  A        2      2000-01-25           0
  A        2      2000-02-04           10
  A        2      2000-02-20           26
  B        1      2000-01-05           0
  B        1      2000-01-13           8
  C        3      2000-04-01           0
```

Edit 1:
Thanks to Jeff and DSM, this worked perfectly:

`df.groupby(["Group", "stage"])["time"].apply(lambda x: x-x.iloc[0])`

Comment: very similar question I and others answered recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889337/dataframe-groupby-return-delta-time-for-log-entries/20889499#20889499

Comment: It's similar, but my problem is that the stage is changing at irregular intervals for each group so I can't just specify the difference with a single location. I need to be constantly updating the referenced date.

Comment: Why is the 02-13 B-1 duration 8 and not 39?

Comment: Good point. Fixed it.

Comment: I may be missing something, but doesn't the sol'n Jeff linked to work for you?  `df.groupby(["Group", "stage"])["time"].apply(lambda x: x-x.iloc[0])`.

Comment: Good point. I hadn't thought of the second level of indexing. However, when I try it I'm getting a cryptic error: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: After converting your `time` column to a datetime, the above works for me.  That's how I found the 8/39 bug.  What version of `pandas` are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 0.12.0. Can't seem to figure out this error. Should it be fixed in 0.13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Jeff and DSM, this worked perfectly:

`df.groupby(["Group", "stage"])["time"].apply(lambda x: x-x.iloc[0])`

Answer (score 0):

you can get days amount between two dates with `datetime.strptime` method.

for example:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime

>>> date1 = "2000-01-25"
>>> date2 = "2000-02-04"
>>> delta = (datetime.strptime(date2,"%Y-%m-%d") - datetime.strptime(date1,"%Y-%m-%d"))
>>> delta.days
10
```

Comment: Thanks. My problem isn't so much finding a difference in dates. It is how to do this particular calculation.