# Vector arithmetic by conditional selection from multiple columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to do arithmetic among different cells in my dataframe and can't figure out how to operate on each of my groups. I'm trying to find the difference in `energy_use` between a baseline building (in this example `upgrade_name == b` is the baseline case) and each upgrade, for each building. I have an arbitrary number of `building_id`'s and arbitrary number of `upgrade_name`s.

I can do this successfully for a single `building_id`. Now I need to expand this out to a full dataset and am stuck. I will have 10's of thousands of buildings and dozens of upgrades for each building.

The answer to this question [Iterating within groups in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21099872/iterating-within-groups-in-pandas) may be related, but I'm not sure how to apply it to my problem.

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'building_id': [1,2,1,2,1], 'upgrade_name': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'], 'energy_use': [100.4, 150.8, 145.1, 136.7, 120.3]})
```

```
In [4]: df
Out[4]:
   building_id upgrade_name  energy_use
0            1            a       100.4
1            2            a       150.8
2            1            b       145.1
3            2            b       136.7
4            1            c       120.3
```

For a single `building_id` I have the following code:

```
upgrades = df.loc[df.building_id == 1, ['upgrade_name', 'energy_use']]
starting_point = upgrades.loc[upgrades.upgrade_name == 'b', 'energy_use']
upgrades['diff'] = upgrades.energy_use - starting_point.values[0]
In [8]: upgrades
Out[8]:
  upgrade_name  energy_use  diff
0            a       100.4 -44.7
2            b       145.1   0.0
4            c       120.3 -24.8
```

How do I write this for arbitrary numbers of building_id's, instead of my hard-coded `building_id == 1`?
The ideal solution looks like this (doesn't matter if the baseline differences are `0` or `NaN`):

```
In [17]: df
Out[17]:
   building_id upgrade_name  energy_use  ideal
0            1            a       100.4  -44.7
1            2            a       150.8   14.1
2            1            b       145.1    0.0
3            2            b       136.7    0.0
4            1            c       120.3  -24.8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the function counting the difference in energy usage (for
a group of rows for the current building) as follows:

```
def euDiff(grp):
    euBase = grp[grp.upgrade_name == 'b'].energy_use.values[0]
    return grp.energy_use - euBase
```

Then compute the difference (for all buildings), applying it to each group:

```
df['ideal'] = df.groupby('building_id').apply(euDiff)\
    .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

The result is just as you expected.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for sharing that example data! Made things a lot easier.

I suggest solving this in two parts:
1. Make a dictionary from your dataframe that contains that baseline energy use for each building
2. Apply a lambda function to your dataframe to subtract each energy use value from the baseline value associated with that building.

```py
# set index to building_id, turn into dictionary, filter out energy use
building_baseline = df[df['upgrade_name'] == 'b'].set_index('building_id').to_dict()['energy_use']

# apply lambda to dataframe, use axis=1 to access rows
df['diff'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['energy_use'] - building_baseline[row['building_id']])
```

You could also write a function to do this. You also don't necessarily need the dictionary, it just makes things easier. If you're curious about these alternative solutions let me know and I can add them for you.